# Error: Unbound record field Server.callback - Ocaml

Tags: webserver, ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I am following a tutorial that explains how to make a simple web server in OCaml with `lwt` and `Cohttp`.

I have a `_tags` file that contains the following:

```
true: package(lwt), package(cohttp), package(cohttp.lwt)
```

And a `webserver.ml`:

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix

let make_server () =
  let callback conn_id req body =
    let uri = Request.uri req in
    match Uri.path uri with
    | "/" -> Server.respond_string ~status:`OK ~body:"hello!\n" ()
    | _ -> Server.respond_string ~status:`Not_found ~body:"Route not found" ()
  in
  let conn_closed conn_id () = () in
  Server.create { Server.callback; Server.conn_closed }

let _ =
  Lwt_unix.run (make_server ())
```

Then, `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind webserver.native` triggers the following error:

```
Error: Unbound record field callback
Command exited with code 2.
```

If I change to: `Server.create { callback; conn_closed }` it will also trigger:

```
Error: Unbound record field callback
Command exited with code 2.
```

I am not sure how to solve this, so thanks in advance for looking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you are using a very outdated tutorial, that was written for an old `cohttp` interface.  You can try to look at the up-to-date tutorials in [the upstream repository](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp).

In your case, at least the following changes should be made, to compile the program:

1. You should use function `Server.make` to create an instance of a server;
2. The `callback` and `conn_closed` values should be passed as function parameters, not as a record, e.g.,

   ```
   Server.make ~callback ~conn_closed ()
   ```
3. You should use function `Server.create` and pass a value, that was returned from function `Server.make` to create a server instance.

So, probably, the following should work:

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix

let make_server () =
  let callback conn_id req body =
    let uri = Request.uri req in
    match Uri.path uri with
    | "/" -> Server.respond_string ~status:`OK ~body:"hello!\n" ()
    | _ -> Server.respond_string ~status:`Not_found ~body:"Route not found" ()
  in
  Server.create (Server.make ~callback ())

let _ =
  Lwt_unix.run (make_server ())
```